# Ruby results are not showing in web browser

Tags: php, ruby

Am running a ruby file using php. When I run the php in the terminal it runs but the execution is a bit slow. When I run the php file on my browser results don't display. When I use a simple command for example 'ls' it runs fine in the terminal and web browser.

below is the script am using in my php file.

```
echo "<pre>";
$display = system('ruby /home/user/ruby-grok/examples/test.rb');
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Is it possible that you do not have permissions to execute this file? Also verify the file really does exist. Maybe run `ls /home/user/ruby-grok/examples/test.rb` and see if it works.

Comment: The file has permissions to execute and the file does exist

Comment: Perhaps PHP's PATH variable is different from the one in your shell, and thus PHP cannot find the Ruby executable. Try running `ruby -v` and see if that generates an error.

Comment: I have tried the -v it doesnt generate an error. Could it have to do with the user? i did a whoami and it gave me www-data.

Comment: Without seeing the contents of test.rb we can't tell you why it isn't outputting something. The file could be empty for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the contents of test.rb we can't tell you why it isn't outputting something. The file could be empty for all we know.

At the same time, you're capturing any output of the `system` command and storing it in `$display` but you're not printing that value. Is the Ruby script returning something or supposed to print it?

Again, without knowing what's in that script we can't help in any real way.